# How to build AWS CodePipeline to deploy ECR containers to ECS Fargate in a cross account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-fargate

I am trying to deploy an ECR container to ECS Fargate in a cross account.
There are 2 account

- Tooling Account
- Development Account
  The Tooling Account is where AWS CodePipeline builds the images and stores the images in ECR.
  The Devlopment Account is where ECS runs the image in Fargate

I have the AWS CodePipeline building the image and storing it in ECR on the Tooling Account.
Now I cannot find any documentation anywhere on how I go about deploying the image in the Development Account.

I have thought of a few options;

1. Create a AWS CodeDeploy in the Tooling Account and deploy the image to Fargate in the Devlopment Account. *issues* - I don't know how AWS CodeDeploy in the Tooling Account can trigger the deployment in another account.
2. Create a AWS CodeDeploy in the Devlopment Account which can deploy to Fargate. *issues* - I don't know how to trigger the AWS CodeDeploy in the Development Account from the Tooling Account.

There is lots of documentation out there on how to run containers on EC2 or Lambda, but not Fargate and especially cross-account Fargate deployment.

I would like to run this all from CloudFormation, but I could build that once I have gotten this working via the console first.

What is the best solution for this achieving this?

Comment: Cross-account deployments are not supported in console if you want to use CP'd cross-account deploy action. So it must be CLI or CFN. The alternative is to use Invoke action in your CP with Lambda function. The lambda function would trigger the deployment in the other account.

Comment: OK @Marcin - do you know where I can find information how to set this up in CFN?  And would this be done where it CP triggers a CD in the Development Account or the CD happens in the Tooling Account?

Comment: The only example (not for CFN) I know of is in [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-create-cross-account.html). The trigger would be in the account where CP is.